# Smart Card Authentication ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, iis, client-certificates

We currently have a site that is hosted within a cloud environment.  Let’s say for sake of discussion, that the site is https://abc.site.com.

We have a wildcard SSL certificate `(*.site.com)` that is used to secure the site.

We have been asked to implement a CAC Card / Smart Card implementation.  Is there a way to read the user’s smart card / client certificate upon a button click?

We are able to read the card in our development environment, but only when we are using the client’s certificate to actually secure the site (which is not how we want this implemented).

I have done a lot of research on this, however I've been unable to find a solution to our problem. From what I've read an `ActiveX` control is the only way to read the client cert store with the smart card cert, but `ActiveX` is not an option for us.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is done at the webserver-layer by requiring a client-side certificate. The user's browser will prompt the user to provide a smartcard (or other certificate). You can ensure they provided a valid smartcard cert by checking the cert's CA roots.

There's an (old) tutorial for ASP.NET here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315588

Other than this, there is no universal way to retrieve a client certificate without resorting to Java applets or ActiveX controls as you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to configure IIS to use client certificates for authentication. You also need to have in the WebServer all certificate chain installed.

And in your ASP.NET Page, you could use `Request.ClientCertificate` to access the certificate informations that you'll use to give authentication on your system.